# Java Program That Deletes Itself - Not Working

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to create a program that creates a copy of itself and deletes the original project folder.

(FYI: Project has its own JRE inside it)
(FYI: This program runs on Windows)

So:

To be able to do that, other than my primary main method, there is a second main method in the class called SelfUpdater.

Inside my main thread I copy the project to a second folder. 
And then run the SelfUpdater's main method inside this second project folder:

This should mean that I'm running a whole new instance, totally unrelated to the first java.exe (which already gets closed with system.exit(0) as soon as new instance starts).

But when I try to delete the first folder, I get the error "Error deleting old client.java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file". **Actually It deletes some of the files, but I can't delete Application.exe and its lib folder.**

**Its folder is not open in windows. It is not being used by anything else. I can't delete the file manually either (Windows says it is in use). And as soon as the second java.exe is terminated, I can delete it.**

I can't give a total working example, But my in my main thread I call this following method:

```
public static void selfUpdate() {

    try {
        String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        String path = null;

        File parentFolder = null;
        File originalClientFolder = new File(rootPath);
        parentFolder = originalClientFolder.getParentFile();

        File secondClientFolder = new File(parentFolder.getAbsolutePath() + separator + "runLAST");
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(originalClientFolder, secondClientFolder);

        path = secondClientFolder.getAbsolutePath() + separator + "jre8" + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(path, "-cp", classpath, SelfUpdater.class.getName(), downloadURL, rootPath);            
        processBuilder.directory(secondClientFolder);
        processBuilder.start();

        System.exit(0);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

And my SelfUpdater class' main is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {                
        String originalClientFolderPath = args[1];
        //
        File oldClientFolder = new File(originalClientFolderPath);

        System.out.println("Deleting old client recursively. Folder: " + oldClientFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(oldClientFolder);
        } catch (Exception ex) {                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The behaviour and permissions for file deletion are operating system dependent. Please add a tag (or update the question if there are many) with the relevant operating system(s).

Comment: In Windows, an open file cannot be deleted. The new instance won't be able to delete the old folder until the old exe has terminated. In Linux/Unix there is no such restriction (but there may be other considerations).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks, Added. Project is for windows only As I said in the post, original exe gets terminated since I call System.exit(0) immidiately. But still, new java.exe can not delete old folder. (Even if I wait with Thread.sleep() for a quite while) I guess second java is somehow is still connected to the original one.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code yet, but my guess is that you're running the second file in some sorting sub prcocess that blocks `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Having a directory open counts as having a file open. So check that you don't have an explorer window open on the old path and that the new exe doesn't have the old directory as current working directory.

Comment: @timotree As I said, first javaw.exe already gets closed. It terminates. It is not in the Task Manager. There is only the second one there. So; I cant be blocking 'System.exit(0)'

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I added some info (bold texts) folder is not open. And for the directory:  `processBuilder.directory(secondClientFolder);` should be for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearently, I forgot to change the classpath.

I'm thinking about leaving the question, since people may need such code part.
But at the end, method that's being called is changed to this:

```
public static void selfUpdate() {

    try {
        String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        String path = null;

        File parentFolder = null;
        File originalClientFolder = new File(rootPath);
        parentFolder = originalClientFolder.getParentFile();

        File secondClientFolder = new File(parentFolder.getAbsolutePath() + separator + "runLAST");
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(originalClientFolder, secondClientFolder);

        // ADDED: --------------------------------------------------------
        String origialClientFolderName = originalClientFolder.getName();
        classpath = classpath.replace(origialClientFolderName, "runLAST");
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------

        path = secondClientFolder.getAbsolutePath() + separator + "jre8" + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(path, "-cp", classpath, SelfUpdater.class.getName(), downloadURL, rootPath);            
        processBuilder.directory(secondClientFolder);
        processBuilder.start();

        System.exit(0);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```